# Logic question with premises

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Put the following syllogism into the standard form, which uses a horizontal line to separate premises and conclusion. Moreover, tell whether it is valid or not by showing its Venn Diagram.

Bill didn't go to work this morning because he wore a sweater, and he never wears a sweater to work.

As far I know, to indicate absence of elements, we use shade, whereas to indicate existence of an element belonging to a class, we mark "$x$" inside the circle. But, I could not associate this rule with given premises. Can anyone suggest their solutions with correct premise-conclusion and Venn diagram?

Note: What is the name of this subject, and where can I read about these concepts?

Comment: Syllogism? Venn diagram ? It seems a propositional logic problem...

Comment: A syllogism has two premises and a conclusion; start identifying into the purported argument above the premise(s) and the conclusion.

Comment: You need to use temporal logic for such expressions (you can read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_logic, for a start).

Comment: If we rewrite it as follows: "If Bill go to work, he does not wear a sweater. Bill wear a sweater. Therefore, Bill do not go to work", then we can formalize it as an argument in propositional logic.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments, we need to write this in a slightly different way to make it better fitted to be written as a syllogism. So, let me read the statement as

"Bill wore a sweater today;

everyday that Bill wears a sweater, he does not go to work;

Bill did not go to work today."

If $t$ stands for "today", $S(x)$ stands for "Bill wore a sweater at day $x$" and $W(x)$ stands for "Bill went to work at day $x$", this gives us the syllogism (sorry for the simply awful appearance...).

$$S(t)$$
$$\forall x\Big(S(x)\rightarrow \neg W(x)\Big)$$
$$\rule{4cm}{0.4pt}$$
$$\neg W(t)$$

Now, to see this as a Venn diagram, start by writing down your propositions (again, sorry for the awful drawings, in a blackboard this would be easier...):

[image]

$S(t)$ means that there is an element in $S$, but we don't know if it is also inside $W$, so we place it in the frontier, as this:

[image]

Now $\forall x(S(x)\rightarrow\neg W(x))$ implies that every element $x$ which satisfies $S$ (that is, $S(x)$), does not satisfy $W$ (that is, $\neg W(x)$); in other words, no element of $S$ is inside $W$, and we can shade the area they share as empty:

[image]

Combining both diagrams, we know the element $t$, we know to be in $S$, can't be also in $W$, given $S\cap W$ is empty, and so must be in $S$ and outside $W$, as below:

[image]

The conclusion is that $t$ is not in $W$, that is, $\neg W(t)$ is true (that is, Bill did not go to work today), and so the argument is, in fact, valid.